# OSX Mail - Folder Locations

Tags: email, exchange, imap

In OSX mail, I have a number of different mailbox types - iCloud, Google Apps, and Exchange. For whatever reason, the Exchange mailbox displays the folders underneath the mailbox list at the top (see picture). iCloud and Google Apps do not do this (both are IMAP). Is there a reason for this? Any way to change that behavior?

[image: Mial Screenshot]

Comment: Change to what position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iCloud/Google Apps you didn’t create the folders *under* “Inbox”, and so they appear further down in the pane you’ve screenshotted.

On the Exchange server you did create folders *under* the “Inbox”, and therefore that is where Mail.app displays them.

On my Zoho (IMAP account), I can either use the web client to create folder under the Inbox, or use Mail.app by ctrl+click on the Inbox I want to create a folder under and selecting “New mailbox...”, in the window that appears prefix the Name of the folder you want to create with “Inbox/” e.g. `Inbox/foo`.
I tried the above on my iCloud account, but it didn’t seem to work.